# Django Rest Framework - Cache 'list' function but not 'retrieve' function (detail) in ModelViewSet

Tags: python, django, caching, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I have the following code:

```
class OrderListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet,
                       ReadOnlyCacheResponseAndETAGMixin):
    permission_classes = (NoUpdatePermission,)
    model_class = Order
    lookup_field = 'unique_reference'
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    pagination_class = OrderPagination

    @method_decorator(cache_page(settings.ORDER_CACHE_LIFETIME))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(OrderListViewSet, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return CreateOrderSerializer

        return super(OrderListViewSet, self).get_serializer_class()

    def get_queryset(self, filters=None, **kwargs):
        self.queryset = Order.objects.all()
        return super(OrderListViewSet, self).get_queryset()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            _create_anonymous_user(self.request)
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

        return super(OrderListViewSet, self).perform_create(serializer)
```

I want to migrate to:

```
class OrderListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet,
                       ReadOnlyCacheResponseAndETAGMixin):
    permission_classes = (NoUpdatePermission,)
    model_class = Order
    lookup_field = 'unique_reference'
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    pagination_class = OrderPagination

    @method_decorator(cache_page(settings.ORDER_CACHE_LIFETIME))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(OrderListViewSet, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return CreateOrderSerializer

        return super(OrderListViewSet, self).get_serializer_class()

    def get_queryset(self, filters=None, **kwargs):
        self.queryset = Order.objects.all()
        return super(OrderListViewSet, self).get_queryset()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            _create_anonymous_user(self.request)
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

        return super(OrderListViewSet, self).perform_create(serializer)
```

My goal is to cache the `ListView` for 60 seconds but not the `DetailView` (always return latest data from there as it is used for long pulling).

The error which I get is:
`TypeError: never_cache() missing 1 required positional argument: 'view_func'`

Would it be reasonable to remove the `never_cache` decorator all together?

Comment: After looking hard and long at both codes, I didn't see a difference. What code are you migrating to?

Comment: hi, I had a mistake, it should be 'list' and 'retrieve' in the code